# Is it possible to change default behavior for "top"?

Tags: linux, top

For example, when I run top I usually press "C" so I can see the explicit command being run not the executable name if you will.

Is there a way I can modify top such that when I do:

```
% top
```

The result is initially displaying the command line and not the executable command?

For example I see initially:

```
chromium-browser
```

But would prefer to see:

```
/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=plugin --plugin-pat
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the version of top, but after pressing the "c", press "W" which will save your preferences in your ~/.toprc file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to an excellent answer of @Kevin,
I want to state that some settings can be passed to `top` from a command line.
So, the problem in question can be solved with a simple aliasing.

For example my alias for top is:

```
alias top='top -u <my_user_name> -c'
```